# Failing to build Xilinx project from command line only

Tags: eclipse, command-line, build, xilinx

I have been tasked with creating a build server for a Xilinx project.  The developer for the project provided me with the steps he manually takes to do a build, and those work fine.  I am now trying to do the build via the command line, so I can set up a script to do the build.  From my understanding, the command:

ECLIPSECPATH\eclipsec.exe -nosplash -vm “JAVAVMPATH\jvm.dll” -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -build all -data WORKSPACE -vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.cdt.core.console=org.eclipse.cdt.core.systemConsole

Should be the correct command to perform the build (the all caps names being file paths to the various files needed).  I use the same command for importing (except -import instead of -build), which does work correctly.  But when I run the command, it returns a bunch of errors that are either "Cannot run program "make": Launching failed" or "Error: Program "make" not found in PATH".

The build works just fine when building from the GUI, and I didn't have to use the Tool Change Editor to change anything (it worked by default).  Am I missing something from my command, or is there something else I need to set?  Are the projects just missing something needed? I'm not a developer, but I would think if it builds from the GUI, the projects have everything they need to build.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project where I run a Xilinx eclipse project in headless mode. It is on a Linux system, but I think what I am about to say applies to windows too.

When one of the Xilinx GUI apps run the first thing they do is source some environment settings. If you are not sourcing this before you run the command line above then you may be missing some paths in the environment, in particular the path to "make" which is not part of windows.

There is a batch file under C:\Xilinx\SDK\2014.4\ (or whichever version you have installed) called settings64.bat.

Running this before the eclipse command line should setup the tool environment you require.

```
C:\Xilinx\SDK\2014.4\settings64.bat
```

As part of the setup I also run this to help setup the workspace.

```
xsdk -wait -script sdk.xml -workspace WORKSPACE
```